# How to configure Apache Spark on Windows?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I would like to to install Apache Spark on my Windows machine. Are there any Windows specific steps I have to follow?

Comment: If the provided answer solved your problem please don't forget to accept. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3):

1. Download `spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz` from [the Spark website](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) and open it, with 7zip for example.
2. Extract it to a folder, for example into C:\sparktest. So my structure is now C:\SparkTest\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\
3. We download hadoop2.6.0 for Windows:
   https://www.barik.net/archive/2015/01/19/172716/
4. We extract it somewhere.
5. In the Spark base folder we go into the `conf` folder where a file named `log4j.properties.template` should be located.
   We delete the template part, so the name should be `log4j.properties`. For our own sanity we can open the file and change `rootCategory` from `INFO` to `WARN`
6. Add the Spark `bin` folder to the `PATH` environment variable of your system.
7. We create an environment variable `SPARK_HOME` which we change to the Spark base folder (`spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6`)
8. We create the `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable which we set to our extracted Hadoop base folder

That's all

Later you have to learn sbt and scala.